# Scrollbar on table not showing in Edge

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, microsoft-edge

I have a scrollbar that is not rendered in Microsoft Edge only, all other browser work like expected.
I have a table with a fixed height and varying content received by webservice call. If there's more content than the set width, I naturally want a vertical scrollbar to show up. So I set `scrollbar: auto` on the table body.

This works fine, *unless* I use an URL parameter. I need this parameter to show the table after page load. If I load the table by clicking on the according button, the scrollbar is visible like it should be.

I can't reproduce this in a fiddle, but the page can be found at: http://dev.heco.de/en/edelstahl/threaded-fittings/fittings/pn-10/sockets/full.html
The table is shown by clicking "stocks and pricing". But if I load the very same page with parameter: http://dev.heco.de/en/edelstahl/threaded-fittings/fittings/pn-10/sockets/full.html?tabId=stocksAndPricing, no scrollbar is shown in Edge.

This is the CSS in use:

```
.fixedprices_content {max-width: 960px;table-layout: fixed;top:0;border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;}
.fixedprices_content tbody {display: block;overflow-x: hidden;width: 100%;background-color: #fff;max-height: 600px;}
```

This has me utterly confused, since the same CSS (and JS) is loaded in both cases. Even if I set `height: 50px!important; overflow:scroll!important; -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;` these stylings are not honored in Edge. They are shown in developer tools, are not marked as overwritten, but checking or unchecking them doesn't change a thing. Is there something I'm too blindsided to see?

Any help and input appreciated!